# Cannot Access Hash Values

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, response

Code inside index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $( ".trashitem" ).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var trashlink = $(this);
                    var res = confirm("Are you sure you want to trash the selected item?");
                    if ( res != false ) {
                        var trashurl = trashlink.attr("href");
                        var trashid = trashlink.data("id");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: trashurl,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { "trashid": trashid },
                            datatype: "json",
                            success: function(response) {
                                console.log(response);  // Output: {"success":true,"error":false}
                                console.log(response.success);  // Output:   undefined
                                if (response.success == true) {
                                    trashlink.parents("li").fadeOut(300, function() {
                                        trashlink.parents("li").remove();
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="trashitem text-color-alert" href="trash.php" data-id="20">Trash</a></li>
            <li>This is undeletable item.</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code inside trash.php is:

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['trashid'];
  $error = false;
  $success = false;
  if ($id) {
    $success = trash_post($id);
    $response = array(
      'success' => $success,
      'error' => $error
    );
  }
  echo json_encode( $response );

  function trash_post( $target_id ) {
    return true;
  }
```

Please look at the first code snippet in index.php where:

```
console.log(response);  // Output: {"success":true,"error":false}
```

but when I want to access `success`:

```
console.log(response.success);  //   undefined
```

Why does it give me `undefined` instead of `true`? I have come across a few posts on Stackoverflow similar to mine, but they were not helpful for me.

Comment: Made some changes to better explain the question and the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `response` is just a string but not a `Object`

try

```
var a = JSON.parse(response);
console.log(a.success);
```

or try adding this at the top of your `php` file

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

this set's the content type of php file as `JSON`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
response['success'] == true
```

Instead of

```
response.success == true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use success or error flags for your response, instead make use of the status codes and build a proper response. You can use `http_response_code()` function to do that. Ex:

```
<?php
http_response_code(200);
?>
```

And then to handle the response in your ajax call properly, do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: trashurl,
    type: "POST",
    data: { "trashid": trashid },
    datatype: "json"
})
  .done(function (response) { //response status code is 200
       trashlink.parents("li").fadeOut(300, function() {
           trashlink.parents("li").remove();
       });
  })
  .fail(function (xh) {
      //Handle failed response
  });
```